# Z-index vs Accessibility

Tags: css, z-index

Here's a simplification of my code that I'm having problems with, in regards to layering.

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li>Option 1
        <ul id="submenu1">
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>                
            <li>link</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Option 2
        <ul id="submenu2">
            <li>link</li>
            <li>link</li>                
            <li>link</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My issue is that submenu2 seems to be above Option 1.  I have tried to give them appropriate z-indexes, but they don't seem to work... I'm assuming because submenu2 is a child of Option 2, and has no relevance to Option 1.

Any idea of any work around that would help resolve my issue?

I'm using large graphics for most of these links, so the overlapping is quite obvious.

Comment: Without the CSS, it's hard to see the problem

Comment: Is the CSS doing anything fancy involving positioning or floats?

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works with absolutely positioned elements. And as my commentators point out, relative and fixed positioning as well. My somewhat hurried point was that the element has to be taken out of the regular document flow.

Comment: False. z-index works with relatively and fixed position elements as well. See the note under Definition and Usage: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Or `relative` or `fixed` position elements. But yeah, my guess is they're `static` here, which is the one value of `position` for which `z-index` is meaningless.

Comment: Option 1, Option 2 are both relatively positioned... and the submenus are absolutely positioned.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was doing a quick drive-by. Edited to reflect your  input.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the CSS, but for z-index to work properly, the element must be positioned either absolutely, relatively, or fixed.

Comment: Option 1, Option 2 are both relatively positioned... and the submenus are absolutely positioned.